# Extract lines starting with IP address from file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

In shell scripting language, I have to extract from a given file only lines starting with IP addresses

example fileX contains:

```
text  
10.0.0.1  host1  
some other text 10.1.1.2  
172.22.0.25 host1 host1.example.com  
12.8  
123  T  
260.1.1.1
```

Expected output:

```
10.0.0.1 host1  
172.22.0.25 host1 host1.example.com
```

Comment: `grep  "^[0-9]\+\."` should do it.

Comment: `grep '^[0-9]' file`  should also do it based on sample given...

Comment: just checked and edited. sorry!

Comment: Thanks but it returns results which are not in IP address format example : 12.8

Comment: @W4hf so your sample input and description needs to reflect that.. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .. see also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: sorry for incomplete description. I have edited it.

Comment: if perl is okay, try `perl -lane '$m=1; foreach (split/\./,$F[0]){$m=0 if $_ > 255} print if $m && $F[0] =~ /^(\d+\.){3}\d+$/' file`

Comment: Use `grep "^[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+ "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that valid IP addresses' octets range from 0 to 255 (some IP numbers are protected, but I am not addressing those), this code should do what you want:

```
grep -Eh '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' /folder/file | awk -F'.' '$1 <=255 && $2 <= 255 && $3 <= 255 && $4 <= 255' > /tmp/result
```

The result is stored on /tmp/result

Comment: With less redundancy: `'^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'`

Comment: Thank you but it gives other unwanted results like 999.1.1.1 for example which is not an IP address

Comment: You folks are right, I forgot that IP numbers have special requirements (0-255). I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -lane 'if($F[0] =~ /^(\d+\.){3}\d+$/){ $m=1; foreach (split/\./,$F[0]){$m=0 if $_ > 255} print if $m }' fileX 
10.0.0.1  host1  
172.22.0.25 host1 host1.example.com
```

- Split input line on spaces, saved in `@F` array
- `if($F[0] =~ /^(\d+\.){3}\d+$/)` check if first field has four sets of digits separated by `.`

  - `$m=1` initialize match variable
  - `foreach (split/\./,$F[0])` split first field on `.` and iterate over them
  - `$m=0 if $_ > 255` clear match variable if any value is greater than 255
  - `print if $m` print input line if all values in first field is less than or equal to 255